# how to use different versions of react and package in the react project besides iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have project that use `react 16` and it has a npm package which is `antd3`, and now I have to add a new package that use `react 17` and `antd4`. I cannot change the package cause it has widely used in many projects.

One solution that I know is build a new project that has the new package, and then I add it into this project. So the question is has any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you name the new package that uses React 17? Assuming it does not work with React 16 (sometimes the developer just gets overzealous and makes the requirements too high, and you can force it to use your version), then the real answer is you need to upgrade your own project to React 17 if you want to use the new package inside a single react tree. Sadly, [incremental upgrades](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#gradual-upgrades) didn't get added until v17 onwards. So v16 --> v17 is all or nothing. It's not so bad though,  usually pain free.

Comment: By the way your proposed solution will do nothing if the new package actually requires react 17 to execute without bugs. But would be good to know what that package is so I can help verify.